# What is the etymology of the "diéresis" or "crema"?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, diacríticos

[This entry](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=di%E9resis) of the *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* explains the uses of the *diéresis* or *crema* (the `¨` mark) in Spanish (it is mandatory over a *u* to indicate that this vowel must be pronounced in the combinations *gue* and *gui*, as in vergüenza, lingüística), but it gives no hints on its origin.

I would like to know the historical origin of this sign.

Comment: I always thought it was called *trema*!

Comment: @hippietrail: well, if you wear a Greek gown, you can also call it *trema* ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29#History) explains it pretty well. It was invented by the Greeks, to mark a vowel that shouldn't be combined with adjacent ones into a diphthong or new sound. With that sense it's been used ever since, even in English (although this usage is almost extint). The word *diaeresis* means *separation*; *crema* comes from *trema*, which is Ancient Greek for *pip* (of dice), another name given to this diacritic by the Greek.